# Recreating grid column filter option

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs6

I have a Grid with filter option.

For some requirement, I need to reconfigure the grid with different set of columns on some button click.  For this I am using reconfigure option of grid as follows-

```
var columnSet = [
      ......
      ......
      some columns
      ......
];

grid.reconfigure(undefined, columnSet);
```

This works fine, but after re-configuring the grids 'Filter' option disappears. I want grids filter option in column menu as it is.
I searched on google and found that reconfigure resets everything and I need to recreate the grids filter.

I tried different approaches suggested like overriding grids filter. But it doesn't work.

Can anybody suggest a simple solution for this instead of oveeriding and all.